# using publish with subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

The goal is that there is one service, and 2 components rely on the service. The update would be triggered externally, and all the components that rely on the data from the service would be notified that new data is available. To do this I'm using a typed subject, that then is published as a connectable observable.

Peeking in the debugger one thing that bothers me is that the refcounts stay 0, but I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding what these mean. Any information as to what to expect and how to troubleshoot this would be awesome.

the components each have identical code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.stepService.stepsFeed.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(`Got Steps in operations`);
      this.availableOperations = val;
    });
    console.log(`subscribed`);
  }
```

The service has the following

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {

    this.stepsSubject = new Subject<StepDefinition[]>();
    this.stepsFeed = this.stepsSubject.pipe(
      tap(_ => {
        this.log('new steps published');
      }),
      publish()
    ) as ConnectableObservable<StepDefinition[]>;

    this.getStepDefinitions()
      .subscribe(operations => {
        this.stepsFeed.connect();
        this.log('connected');
      });
  }

  private stepsUrl = 'api/steps';

  private stepsSubject: Subject<StepDefinition[]>;
  public stepsFeed: ConnectableObservable<StepDefinition[]>;

  private getStepDefinitions(): Observable<StepDefinition[]> {
    return this.http.get<StepDefinition[]>(this.stepsUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(steps =>
        {
          this.stepsSubject.next(steps);
          this.log('fetched steps');
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('getStepDefinitions', []))
      );
  }
```

The output is as follows:

```
subscribed
subscribed
fetched steps
connected
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to publish a subject. It's already a multicast observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
const subscribeTwo = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

//share observable among subscribers
const sharedExample = example.pipe(share());
```